# Problems when reading integers with scanf

Tags: io, scanf

I know that it might be a stupid question but can you tell me why the following patch of code fails? I see nothing wrong. I am trying to read integers using scanf. I have included the necessary library, but when I run the program it crashes after I read the first s. Thank you.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, x;

    scanf("%d", &n); scanf("%d", &x);

    vector< pair<int, int> > moments;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int f, s;
        scanf("%d", &f);
        scanf("%d", &s );

        moments[i].first = f;
        moments[i].second = s;

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way to assign values to moments since moments[i] does not yet exist.  Try:

```
    pair<int, int> thing;
    thing = make_pair(f,s);
    moments.push_back(thing);
```

instead of your assignements to moments elements.